# Wrap every plugin separately in Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I would like to wrap every plug-in that is added to a page in my Django CMS in specific HTML. So, starting with a template

```
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
<body>
```

And TextPlugin elements on the page which render as say

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

and

```
<p>dolor sit amet</p>
```

to actually render as a page that looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
  <div class="wrapper"><p>dolor sit amet</p></div>      
</body>
```

I had a look at [djangocms-cascade](https://github.com/jrief/djangocms-cascade) but it doesn't seem to provide exactly what I am looking for and the migrations fail on my django-cms 3.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Plugin Processors for django-cms. See http://docs.django-cms.org/en/3.2.2/how_to/custom_plugins.html#plugin-processors

In your settings.py:

```
CMS_PLUGIN_PROCESSORS = (
    'yourapp.cms_plugin_processors.wrap_plugin',
)
```

In your yourapp.cms_plugin_processors.py:

```
from django.template import Context, Template

def wrap_plugin(instance, placeholder, rendered_content, original_context):
    t = Template('<div class="wrapper">{{ content|safe }}</div>')
    c = Context({
        'content': rendered_content
    })
    return t.render(c)
```